# Mod cluster configuring sticky session attribute name

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, proxypass, mod-cluster, sticky-session

Is it possible to configure the sticky session attribute name in mod-cluster?

I need to use a name different to JSESSIONID.

I´ve tried

```
ProxyPass / balancer://xxxxx/ stickysession=TESTSESSIONID|testsessionid

ProxyPassReverse / balancer://xxxxx/
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Discussion in mod-cluster forum: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/275361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible till now.

There is a request for enhancement: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/MODCLUSTER-609